# Flatpickr formate with 12hr along with AM/PM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flatpickr

In react js use this option for time show in 12 Hr format eg. "4:45 AM"
 options={{
    enableTime: true,
    noCalendar: true,
    dateFormat: "h:i K",
    }}

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```html
<Flatpickr
  value={requestDate}
  onChange={(date) => setRequestDate(date)}
  options={{
    enableTime: true,
    noCalendar: true,
    dateFormat: "h:i K"
  }}
  id="default-picker"
/>
```

Comment: I should've just started w/ stackoverflow. Finding that 'K' was impossible to track down. Thanks Sudhir and Muhammed!